# Value of a double indexed product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

Let $n$ be a positive integer.
While trying to calculate the product $\prod_{1\leq i\leq j \leq n}^{} ij $, my approach was to write :
$$\prod_{1\leq i\leq j \leq n}^{} ij=\prod_{j=1}^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{j} ij$$
But I am not sure if this is correct or not. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: This is good so far. You can at least "evaluate" the product over $i$ easily. After that.. I'm not sure. After searching, I think this ends up being related to the Barnes $G$ function. I don't know if this simplifies any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is valid. You are just traversing the same set of $(i,j)$ that constitute your index set in a different order. But you should note that

- This would be true for any $a_{i,j}$, not just $a_{i,j} = i \cdot j$.
- You couldn't automatically do this if your index set was infinite.
- As @CameronWilliams' comment points out, while it is valid it may or may not be useful.